# How do I import KerasClassifier now?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

How to import KerasClassifier for use with Gridsearch?

The following

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
```

Used to work, but now returns:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers'
```

I understand there have been several changes to Tensorflow and Keras. I would prefer not to just install an older version, so I'm working to figure out how to use this going foward.

Reading elsewhere, it sounds like this may have been deprecated and replaced by SciKeras, but it sounds like that may also require a lot of other changes to the code.  I have many instances of doing fits and using the history.

Is making that switch the best way given a limited timeframe?  Should I just go to an older version?

Currently running tf version 2.13.0 and keras version 2.13.1 and I've recently updated both so don't think it's a version mismatch item.  It may be I just need to take both back to 2.12.

Comment: Downgrading to 2.12.0 temporarily solves the issue, but still looking for a way to work with the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed changes in [adriangb.com/scikeras](https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html) worked for me. I could use `GridSearch`. Also had to first install `scikeras`:

```
pip install scikeras
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**